# How do I break out of a series of string replace( )?

Tags: javascript

I have a collection of short strings in the form [a][z] where a and z are (component) substrings. The strings that can go in [z] are limited to about 100, and only one of them can appear in the whole input string.

Now, I need to replace the [z] string into another string. Given the data format, as soon as I find a match, I know I can stop looking. I want to return the replaced string.

My approach is suboptimal because I loop through all possibilities before returning the modified string. I'd like to know if there's a way to break the search, possibly using the fact that the input string is changed when there's a match? How can I tell that the replacement happened? I need to run this function about 1000 times per page load so I think that any improvement will be noticed. Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/MsWAZ/3/

```
function replaceEnd(input) {
        // bb, cc, and d are what I call [z]
        input = input.replace("bb", "Bob");
        input = input.replace("ccc", "Carl");
        input = input.replace("d", "Dave");

        return input;
}

document.write(replaceEnd("aabb") + "<br>");
document.write(replaceEnd("eaccc") + "<br>");
document.write(replaceEnd("uoid") + "<br>");
```

Outputs:

```
aaBob
eaCarl
uoiDave
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function replaceEnd(input) {
        // bb, cc, and d are what I call [z]
        var replacements = {"bb" : "Bob", "ccc" : "Carl", "d" : "Dave"}, newInput;
    for(var key in replacements){
        if((newInput = input.replace(key,replacements[key])) != input)
            return newInput;
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, quick and dirty profiling showed approximately the same performance but I think the object approach is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

```
function replaceEnd(input) {
    input2 = input;
    // bb, cc, and d are what I call [z]
    if((input2 = input.replace("bb", "Bob")) != input) return input2;
    if((input2 = input.replace("ccc", "Carl")) != input) return input2;
    if((input2 = input.replace("d", "Dave")) != input) return input2;

    return input2;
}
```